# in the context of binary classification, is the output a class or a classification?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/4IAXaixaLWE?t=103)

> you can think of machine learning, deep learning in
>   general as modeling a function   that takes an input that can be an
>   image, a speech, a natural language or a CSV file, give it to a box and
>   get an output that can be classification

here is the procedure of how a computer program solve the binary classification problem.

you give the computer program an image.

1. if there is a cat on this image, the program outputs 1.
2. if there is no cat on this image, the program outputs 0.

in this context, what the program outputs is a class or a classification?

Comment: @JasonBassford thanks for your reminder. already fixed it.

Comment: So, the lecturer says that the output is *classification*. Is there a reason you suspect that to be wrong? Or are you asking about the general differences between *class*, *classification*, and, perhaps, *classified*?

Comment: Are questions about computer science jargon within the scope of this site, or would they be better suited for more specialist StackExchange sites?